# Inconsistent ReadDocumentCollectionAsync behavior in CosmosDb

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am currently writing a new endpoint for a service (an Azure WebApp that uses CosmosDb written in Core 2.0).  This endpoint (called /verify) is intended to check the availability of all dependent resources and report if they’re all available.  In the current CosmosDb documentation it says this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readdocumentcollectionasync?view=azure-dotnet

DocumentClientException
This exception can encapsulate many different types of errors. To determine the specific error always look at the StatusCode property. Some common codes you may get when creating a Document are:
StatusCode  Reason for exception
404 NotFound - This means the resource you tried to read did not exist.
429 TooManyRequests - This means you have exceeded the number of request units per second. Consult the DocumentClientException.RetryAfter value to see how long you should wait before retrying this operation.

According to the documentation, if you try to read a collection that does not exist, it should throw a DocumentClientException with a status code of 404.  Another project that uses the /verify endpoint that was developed earlier (2-3 weeks ago) used this behavior to check for the existence of the collection.

It seems that this method’s behavior is inconsistent.  In an older Azure Function (v1 written in .NET Framework 4.6.1), this method returns the expected behavior.

The new behavior in the WebApp is that the method *always* returns a success and creates the new collection you’re checking for.  So, for testing purposes, if I check for “TestCollection” (which does not exist), the method now creates the collection I was looking for and returns success.

Here is the code in my common library that works in the Function, but now has the newly described behavior:

```
public async Task<bool> CollectionExistsAsync(string _databaseId, string _collectionId)
    {
        bool success = true;

        try
        {
            await documentClient.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseId, _collectionId));
        }
        catch(DocumentClientException e)
        {
            if(e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        return success;
    }
```

The calling code for the function and the web app are almost identical.

Function App code:

```
if ((verifyManager.CollectionExistsAsync(calendarDatabaseId, calendarCollectionId)).Result == false)
        {
            resourcesAvailable = false;
            issueSource = "Cosmos Calendar";
        }
```

Web App Code:

```
if (!(resultsManager.CollectionExistsAsync(functionSettings.ResultSetDatabaseId, functionSettings.ResultSetCollectionId)).Result)
        {
            resourcesAvailable = false;
            issueSource = "Cosmos Results";
        }
```

Can someone please help me understand why identical code consuming the same library has such dramatic differences in behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: We do not have code in our .NET SDK which creates a container for you if you attempt to read it. I suspect you have some code or some other library you're using that does it for you.

That said, the Mongo API has this behavior, so if you're using any Mongo libraries, you might see this. But that shouldn't matter if you're just using the SQL API.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  We found the issue and this ticket can be closed.  There was an older version of a method in the shared library we had developed that *did* auto-create databases.  The startup.cs code in the web app was using this older method and was creating the databases at instantiation time, not when the /verify endpoint was being called, thus my confusion.  I switched to using the other method and the issue is gone, so it wasn't inconsistent behavior at all in the SDK or in Cosmos.  It was an older overloaded version of a method that was doing it at startup.  Thanks!